# Integer YYYYMMDD to DateTime (e.g. 01JAN2021)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, datetime

I'm having some difficulties converting an integer-type column of a Pandas DataFrame representing dates (in YYYYMMDD format) to a DateTime type column and parsing the result in a specific format (e.g., 01JAN2021). Here's a sample DataFrame to get started:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data={"CUS_DATE": [19550703, 19631212, 19720319, 19890205, 19900726]})

print(df)

   CUS_DATE
0  19550703
1  19631212
2  19720319
3  19890205
4  19900726
```

Of all the things I have tried so far, the only one that worked was the following:

```
df["CUS_DATE"] = pd.to_datetime(df['CUS_DATE'], format='%Y%m%d')

print(df)

    CUS_DATE
0 1955-07-03
1 1963-12-12
2 1972-03-19
3 1989-02-05
4 1990-07-26
```

But the above is not the result I'm looking for. My desired output should be the following:

```
    CUS_DATE
0  03JUL1955
1  12DEC1963
2  19MAR1972
3  05FEB1989
4  26JUL1990
```

Any additional help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do this:

```
In [1347]: df["CUS_DATE"] = pd.to_datetime(df['CUS_DATE'], format='%Y%m%d')
In [1359]: df["CUS_DATE"] = df["CUS_DATE"].apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%d%b%Y').upper())

In [1360]: df
Out[1360]: 
    CUS_DATE
0  03JUL1955
1  12DEC1963
2  19MAR1972
3  05FEB1989
4  26JUL1990
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use, in addition to [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), the methods [`pandas.Series.dt.strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html) and [`pandas.Series.str.upper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.upper.html):

```
df["CUS_DATE"] = (pd.to_datetime(df['CUS_DATE'], format='%Y%m%d')
                    .dt.strftime('%d%b%Y').str.upper())
#    CUS_DATE
#0  03JUL1955
#1  12DEC1963
#2  19MAR1972
#3  05FEB1989
#4  26JUL1990
```

Also, check [this documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) where you can find the datetime format codes.